# Kotlin File vs Class. Whats the difference?

Tags: file, class, kotlin

Just started using Kotlin and created some activities as Kotlin Files. They work, but still, I want to know what the difference between creating a File and a Class.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

[image: icon] Kotlin Class: Android Studio displays it with no extension if the file contains ONLY ONE class.

Unlike Java, Kotlin allows you to put certain things outside the class like:

- extension functions
- constants

If you, therefore, add any of the above or another class to the file, Android Studio will change it to "Kotlin File":

[image: icon] with extension .kt

Removing the above extras, will again show the file as "Kotlin Class"

Comment: So, if I put a `private const val TAG = "MyActivity"` at the top simply for the purpose of Log.d messages, it turns my class into a file. I know it's not really a problem, but is there a better place to put that?

Comment: @Octopus IMO this is the best place to put it if you want a private, static constant. You limit the scope to the file so a class inside this file can use it and this is pretty much the same as private static String from Java.

Comment: So pretty much ignore it and let AS figure it out!

Comment: @Octopus by using companion object you can achive in class level also

Comment: Terrible design choice (I assume by JetBrains). It's never a good idea to obfuscate a programmer's tools for no reason. Just by showing the ".kt" extension always, this StackOverflow question would be unnecessary and no one would care.

Answer (score 71):

The only difference is that creating a file creates a file with no classes, and creating a class creates a file with one class. You can then add more classes to the file, or delete classes, or make any other changes - the end result doesn't depend on how the file was created.

Comment: This should be the decent answer

Comment: whats the added advantage with this i mean having more classes in a single file?

Answer (score 10):

Here is the answer from the official [Documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#source-file-names):

> If a Kotlin file contains a single class (potentially with related
>   top-level declarations), its name should be the same as the name of
>   the class, with the .kt extension appended. If a file contains
>   multiple classes, or only top-level declarations, choose a name
>   describing what the file contains, and name the file accordingly. Use
>   camel humps with an uppercase first letter (e.g.
>   ProcessDeclarations.kt).
>
> The name of the file should describe what the code in the file does.
>   Therefore, you should avoid using meaningless words such as "Util" in
>   file names.

so basically a file can -for instance- contains just (helper-)functions without any class declaration.

Answer (score 2):

As I can see Kotlin file has many classes inside it But a Kotlin class has one class with that name, that's only an observation though.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you define more than one class, it will be automatically converted to file, otherwise it will be automatically converted to class. Usually I think if you need to define some variables or methods that can be directly referenced, you can put them in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a file creates public final class at bytecode level just like creating a class. If You declare a class in a file then two classes will be created at the bytecode level. Therefore, the file exists for convenience - it contains code unrelated to defining the behavior of objects

Answer (score 0):

**The difference is:**

- Kotlin *Class* can have *only a class*.
- Kotlin ***File*** can have ***many classes***.

Answer (score 0):

I found a **further difference** - when it comes to **renaming** files, the refactoring mechanism handles Kotlin files and class files differently:

- *Class:* On renaming the file, the refactoring also renames the contained class itself. This also works vice-versa, so when the class is renamed, also the file is renamed.
- *File:* When renaming a file, only the file is renamed and the contained class name is untouched.

I assume this is done that way because the class name should be kept consistent to the file name in case of Kotlin class files, for a better overview.